# QT creator and Designer difference - Starting QT

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qt-designer

I am trying to learn the QT framework so that I could develop GUI based C++ applications using QT. I am currently using Windows 7 64bit . So far I have just downloaded the QT library from [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads). All the tutorials I came across use QT Creator and I only have QT designer.
My question is should I download QT creator ? if so which one ? Can I simply use forms created in QT designer in my visual studio 2010 console app ?? Any suggestions or links that might help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Qt designer** is a **part of IDE**, it is used to generate a code for widgets(look and fill interface);
Qt creator is IDE;
If you used to work with Visual studio 2010, I advice you to download Qt plugin for it(http://qt-project.org/downloads), which allows to enjoy Qt library in VS (it provides Qt designer).
I have the expirience both with Qt Creator and VS 2010 plugin, difference is subtle.

Answer (score 1):

From QT's own [forum](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/16885)

> QT Designer is for designing dialog's and Main Windows.  QT Creator
>   is a full IDE for developing your programs  It comes with an
>   integrated version of Qt Designer.

Comment: so should i download `Qt Creator 2.7.0 for Windows (51 MB)` will it work with `Qt libraries 4.8.4 for Windows (VS 2010, 234 MB)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm asking for a good re-confirmation! (don't take it otherwise)..
As I'm quite new in the Qt platform, I've found it quite confusing!!
In Windows platform, you've:
 Qt 5.4.1 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2012, OpenGL)  which is a whooping 644 MB file!
& also the info about "Qt Creator" in download says:

> Blockquote 
>   Qt Creator 3.3.1 is included in the Qt 5.4.1 binary packages. 
>   If you need a standalone installer, please select the file according to your operating system from the list below to get the latest Qt Creator for your computer

--- this a layman would understand as Qt Creator is the GUI of Qt IDE & also you need to download "Qt 5.4.1 for Windows" which is a whooping 644MB !!
so, is this the case? 
or I've to download just the Qt Creator for my work?